# UILabel in storyboard with U+2028 character to separate text onto two lines rendering garbage on one device

Tags: ios, unicode, uilabel, newline, uistoryboard

I have a two-word fixed text label that is manually split onto two lines using a line separator character U+2028. It has worked just fine like that for ages, but recently a user has reported seeing `â€"` where that separator is supposed to be.

I know I could use a regular newline character in the storyboard by pasting it in, or <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> on the text field in the IB Attributes Inspector, or I could use AutoLayout to set a fixed size, but I am specifically wondering what could cause this character (which is supposed to be [Apple's unambiguous line separator](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsParagraphBreaks.html) `NSLineSeparatorCharacter`)  to break on a specific device but not on other devices.

The `UILabel` is using the system font, I have not modified it directly using attributed strings or anything. Doesn't look like it's using a different font on the user's device; don't see why it should be anyway. I thought maybe it could have something to do with language/region but I tried changing that and was unable to reproduce it. The device is running iOS 12.

Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: UILabel doesn’t use pure Cocoa / Text Kit. The `numberOfLines` property involves some complications. Use a text view instead, or draw directly with Text Kit yourself. Or just use 2029 instead. Also see http://openradar.appspot.com/22784299

Comment: Why does it work on most devices but not this one? And why is 2029 better? Also yea, I saw that radar and that's why I mentioned I wasn't using attributed strings.

Comment: I don't see how we can know why it doesn't work on that device unless we can reproduce it. I don't know what you are really doing or what kind of device it might be. I tried `lab.numberOfLines = 2; lab.text = "test\u{2028}test"` and it does seem to work, but so does `2029` or `\n` (which is what I always use). I guess I would just follow the path of least resistance and do something that works.

Comment: Yea I'm probably going to wind up just using a regular newline — it's a bit ugly in the source code representation of the storyboard, since it actually separates the line that may be why the original developer did it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like another developer introduced these characters into the label through a merge conflict fix. Didn't realize because I didn't know that the app with the problem was built off of a different branch. Encoding comes into play certainly, but probably because apparently Xcode messed up the unicode character while resolving the conflict.

Comment: So I was right.